# How do I go to, and finish one sub function, and then revert back to the "menu function" that I came from? (python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, menu

Ideally, I'd like there to be a step in the "Add Movie" process that confirms that it's an integer for the year, and once it's accepted, to continue back to the main menu once the movie has been added successfully...

(I'm not going to ask or into how I'd love for it to save user input data to a file to be pulled from so it's not like I'm making a new entry every time, haha)

Here's what I've got... and again, this is my effort after maybe 4 hours of a 27 hour course.

I'm hoping you guys can understand what I'm trying to accomplish... but it's just not "finishing" correctly after the "add movie" function... you should see what I'm talking about.

```
import sys
import random
import os

movies = []

def menu():
    print("Welcome to 'The Movie Program!!'")
    print("(A)dd movie to your list")
    print("(L)ist movies you've added")
    print("(S)earch for movies in your list")
    user_input = str(input("Which function would you like to do?:\n\n""Selection: ").capitalize())
    while user_input != 'Q':
        if user_input == 'A':
            add_movies()
        elif user_input == 'L':
            show_movies()
        elif user_input == 'A':
            search_movies()
        else:
            print("\n\n--Unknown command--Please try again.\n")
            menu()

            #user_input = str(input("\nWhich function would you like to do?:\n"
            #                   "(A)dd movie to your list\n"
            #                   "(L)ist movies you've added\n"
            #                   "(S)earch for movies in your list\n\n""Selection: ").capitalize())


def add_movies():
    name = (input('What is the title of the movie?: ').title())
    director = str(input("Who was the director of this movie?: ").title())
    while True:
        try:
            year = int(input("What was the release year?: "))
            return year
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Only numbers, please.")
        year = False

        #return year

        #if year < 0:
        #    print("Sorry,your response must not be negative.")
        #    continue
        #else:
        #    return year

    movies.append({
        "name": name,
        "director": director,
        "year": year
    })


def show_movies():
    movies[::3]
    for c, value in enumerate(movies, 1):
        print(c, value)
    for movie in movies:
        print(f"Name: {movie['name']}")
        print(f"Director: {movie['director']}")
        print(f"Release Year: {movie['year']}\n")
'''Not done yet
def search_movies():
    movies
    print("This is where you'd see a list of movies in your database")

'''
menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

put

```
user_input = str(input("Which function would you like to do?:\n\n""Selection: ").capitalize())
```

inside of while-loop and give user_input value before loop.

like that:

```
print("Welcome to 'The Movie Program!!'")
print("(A)dd movie to your list")
print("(L)ist movies you've added")
print("(S)earch for movies in your list")
user_input=str(input("Which function would you like to do?:\n\n""Selection: ").capitalize())
while user_input != 'Q':
    if user_input == 'A':
        add_movies()
    elif user_input == 'L':
        show_movies()
    elif user_input == 'A':
        search_movies()
    else:
        print("\n\n--Unknown command--Please try again.\n")
        print("Welcome to 'The Movie Program!!'")
        print("(A)dd movie to your list")
        print("(L)ist movies you've added")
        print("(S)earch for movies in your list")
    user_input = str(input("Which function would you like to do?:\n\n""Selection: ").capitalize())
```

Also you should make movies as variable and returnvalue for functions or make it a global variable.

Comment: I added the str(input... into the loop and it got back to the main selection menu, but when I pressed, "L" to "List" the movies, it just asked for another Movie Title/director...

Comment: Is that maybe because the "While" is still true?

Comment: do you want it to show print("Welcome to 'The Movie Program!!'") and the options every time after user has chosen some option?